# Haar-cascade training took very little time and no xml was produced

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to train a new haar-cascade for faces.

I have a positive dataset of 2000 **cropped** face images (**just the face**) and 3321 negative random images.

I created positive's list using the following command:

```
opencv_createsamples.exe -info info.txt -vec vector.vec -num 2000 -w 10 -h 10
```

Where the file info.txt contains the following lines:

```
AJ_Cook_0001.ppm 1 0 0 64 64
AJ_Lamas_0001.ppm 1 0 0 64 64
Aaron_Eckhart_0001.ppm 1 0 0 64 64
Aaron_Guiel_0001.ppm 1 0 0 64 64
Aaron_Patterson_0001.ppm 1 0 0 64 64
Aaron_Peirsol_0001.ppm 1 0 0 64 64
```

Afterwords, I ran haar_training using the following command:

```
opencv_haartraining.exe -data harrcascade -vec vector.vec -bg infofile.txt -nstages 20 -minhitrate 0.9999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -npos 2000 -nneg 3321 -w 10 -h 10 -nonsym -mem 1024
```

Where the file infofile.txt contains the names of the background images:

```
Bing_000527adc064a067a7f7986f00b140fe.jpg
Bing_002744f85b0bee37f489f43fad5f613f.jpg
Bing_0048e7e5e487203dedba9feb03696b1e.jpg
Bing_00513e8879f4f544717df2c8ea0494b1.jpg
Bing_00543a6cf117f559a05f0fb7e10bd361.jpg
```

Training took about only an two hours and no xml file was generated. The folder harrcascade contains 20 folder with a txt file named 'AdaBoostCARTHaarClassifier.txt' but no xml was generated.

I have two questions:

1. Why did training took so very little time?
2. Why no xml file was generated?

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Gil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093268/training-a-haar-cascade-took-very-little-time/21093695#21093695).  If no xml file was produced, it is very likely that you have run out of positive samples.  Try using 1500 instead of 2000.

Better yet, check out [trainCascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html), a function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox for Matlab, which lets you generate an xml file compatible with OpenCV.